# Is there anyway to remove duplicates from a dataframe based on certain conditions?

Tags: r

I am looking to remove duplicates from my code with the `distinct()` function, however I don't want it to remove some duplicates based on an additional condition.

For example, my data frame has variables of `position`, `place`, `company`, and `source`, so I want the rows of duplicates only to be removed when `position`, `place`, and `company` are the same, and while the `source` variable is different. This is the function I am using.

```
omit <- distinct(final, position, place, company, .keep_all = TRUE)
```

I just want the duplicates to be removed when they are matching for three variables, while remaining different for the other one. Is there some other way this could be done?

Comment: Doesn't that work?

Comment: `duplicated()` will return booleans you can combine with your other conditions.

Comment: @StephenHenderson No, because I need it to follow the additional condition that it removes the duplicates only if the source variables do not match.

Comment: @Alexis I will have to try that, thanks.

Comment: OK pardon my confusion - then that is just `distinct(final, .keep_all = TRUE)` ?

Comment: @StephenHenderson Yeah.

Comment: @StephenHenderson, no because then when `source` is different, it will keep them.

Answer (score 1):

Using base R, you can index duplicates and then subset to your original data frame :

```r
set.seed(123)
dd <- data.frame(matrix(sample(1:2, 10*3, TRUE), ncol = 3), "fv" = gl(2, 5,labels = letters[1:2]))
unique(dd) # 7 unique rows with all variables
#>    X1 X2 X3 fv
#> 1   1  2  2  a
#> 2   2  1  2  a
#> 4   2  2  2  a
#> 6   1  2  2  b
#> 7   2  1  2  b
#> 9   2  1  1  b
#> 10  1  2  1  b
col_dup <- names(dd)[1:3] # set which set of columns to get duplicated from
# unique(dd[,col_dup]) # what you expect in final for those rows

ind_dup <- duplicated(dd[,col_dup]) # get index of duplicated elements
new_dd <- dd[!ind_dup,]
new_dd
#>    X1 X2 X3 fv
#> 1   1  2  2  a
#> 2   2  1  2  a
#> 4   2  2  2  a
#> 9   2  1  1  b
#> 10  1  2  1  b
```